# How to add a value in a dictionary while looping through it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary, and according to the values I have, I want to create another 'variable'; and to put it in the dictionary. I am able to create the other variable but what I'm trying to do to put it in the dictionary is not working. My code is:

```
mydict = {'1':('a','example'),'2':('b','example'),'3':('c','example'),'4':('d','example')}

def to_use (dictionary):
    for key, val in dictionary.iteritems():
        if len(val) == 1:
            if val[0] == 'a':
                new = 'var_a'
            elif val[0] == 'b':
                new = 'test_b'
            elif val[0] == 'c':
                new = 'var_c'
            elif val[0] == 'd':
                new = 'test_d'
        new_dict[key.lower()].append(new)

to_use(mydict)
```

The last line in the function is supposed to create another dictionary (but is not) because I am not sure I can reach to my final dictionary without creating a new dictionary.
What I would like to have is:

```
mydict = {'1':('a','example','var_a'),'2':('b','example','test_b'),'3':('c','example','var_c'),'4':('d','example','test_d')}
```

If anyone has any solution..
Thanks!

Comment: You can't append to tuples since they are immutable. You need lists instead.

Comment: `(but is not)` Well, why is it not working as intended? read and post the error messages, they are clues.

Comment: It is giving me a keyerror, returning the first key found.
I know that tuples are immutable but the idea was to create a new dictionary first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are multiple problems with the code.
Let me try and address them one by one.

1) tuples are immutable
Your dictionary values are tuples and thus cannot be changed.
You can **either** change them to a list by `['a','example']` instead of `('a','example')`.

**Or** replace them with a new tuple during your loop.

```
dictionary[key] = val + (new,)
```

2) You are checking for a length of 1 using `if len(val) == 1:`. For your example data this is never true. Thus there is no `new` variable when you reach `new_dict[key.lower()].append(new)`.

I would suggest to remove the if statement.

3) You never declared `new_dict` to be a dictionary therefore `new_dict[key.lower()].append(new)` fails.

Try the following code using tuples:

```
mydict = {'1':('a','example'),'2':('b','example'),'3':('c','example'),'4':('d','example')}

def to_use (dictionary):
    for key, val in dictionary.iteritems():
        if val[0] == 'a':
            new = 'var_a'
        elif val[0] == 'b':
            new = 'test_b'
        elif val[0] == 'c':
            new = 'var_c'
        elif val[0] == 'd':
            new = 'test_d'
        else:
            new = None
        if new is not None:
            dictionary[key] = val + (new,)

to_use(mydict)
```

Or the following code using lists:

```
mydict = {'1':['a','example'],'2':['b','example'],'3':['c','example'],'4':['d','example']}

def to_use (dictionary):
    for key, val in dictionary.iteritems():
        if val[0] == 'a':
            new = 'var_a'
        elif val[0] == 'b':
            new = 'test_b'
        elif val[0] == 'c':
            new = 'var_c'
        elif val[0] == 'd':
            new = 'test_d'
        else:
            new = None
        if new is not None:
            dictionary[key].append(new)

to_use(mydict)
```

Both should work as you expect.

Comment: Hi codingpoets, thank you for the feedback! You are right that it was a problem with the length, I've corrected it. I've tried your code after, but nothing is happening, this is telling me : TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
And when I try to create a new dictionary like: newdict[key] = val + (new,) nothing is happening, the new dictionary is empty..

Comment: @LoC
I probably should have marked the **Or** more clearly for the two options. You probably mixed the two solutions. I meant for you to **either** change the values from tuples to lists, **or** use `dictionary[key] = val + (new,)`. Make sure that you use your original `mydict` value with the code and not the adapted one. I modified my answer to include both versions. I hope that makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to make a dictionary of the values to be added for each tuple which will simplify the lookup of e.g. `a` with `var_a`, and use it to create a new dictionary like so

```
mydict = {'1':('a','example'),'2':('b','example'),'3':('c','example'),'4':('d','example')}

def to_use(dictionary):

    # Mapping of element to add to tuple
    mapping = {'a': 'var_a', 'b': 'test_b', 'c': 'var_c', 'd': 'test_d'}

    #Iterate through dictionary
    for key, val in dictionary.iteritems():
        #For each key, add a 1 element-tuple to each value
        dictionary[key] = val + (mapping[val[0]],)

    return dictionary

print(to_use(mydict))
```

The output will be

```
{'1': ('a', 'example', 'var_a'), 
'2': ('b', 'example', 'test_b'), 
'3': ('c', 'example', 'var_c'), 
'4': ('d', 'example', 'test_d')}
```

Comment: Thank you Devesh but sadly I can not do manually the dictionary mapping but I have thousands of possibilities. The idea of this code was to create this mapping dictionary at least, because after that I can deal with it. But even that, I'm not able to do it.

Comment: But your thousand of possibilites must be listed somewhere, say in a text file, you can use that to create that mapping dictionary it is much better than having thousand if else

Comment: I'm listing the cases when the length of the 1st value is 1, 2, and then I put something with >2 to cover all possibilities because I can't predict the length of them. I can't cover all possibilities even in an excel file. My program is covering them all, now I just search to create a dictionary between the key and the new variable I create.

Comment: which program covers the possibilities, also you can generate your possibilities using itertools.product or itertools.combinations as well. Take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html

Comment: Hi @LoC did my suggestion make sense to you? If yes please consider upvoting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by declaring the new dictionary I create as defaultdict(list).

Thanks for the help!